# UWP - Button VisualState Focused is not working properly

Tags: c#, uwp, background-foreground, visualstates

I'm trying to change the font color of a button when the button is clicked. I have tried many different things but none have worked. This is the latest thing I tried and what I believe should be the answer but it's not working. Can someone help? PointerOver isworking fine, but Focused is not doing anything when the button is clicked.
After click I want the color to remain applied until another button is clicked, then the text in the new button clicked will change color and the previous button clicked will go back to the default color.

I have tried Pressed and focused state both but none is working.

```
        <Style x:Key="ButtonMenuItemStyle"
           TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="Background"
                Value="Transparent" />
        <Setter Property="Foreground"
                Value="{x:Bind ViewModel.LeftNavMenuPrimaryTextColor}" />
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush"
                Value="{ThemeResource ButtonBorderBrush}" />
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness"
                Value="0" />
        <Setter Property="Padding"
                Value="0" />
        <Setter Property="AllowFocusOnInteraction"
                Value="True" />
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment"
                Value="Stretch" />
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment"
                Value="Stretch"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment"
                Value="Stretch"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment"
                Value="Stretch" />
        <Setter Property="Height"
                Value="65"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="FontFamily"
                Value="{ThemeResource ContentControlThemeFontFamily}" />
        <Setter Property="FontWeight"
                Value="Normal" />
        <Setter Property="FontSize"
                Value="{ThemeResource ControlContentThemeFontSize}" />
        <Setter Property="UseSystemFocusVisuals"
                Value="False" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentPresenter"
                                      AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw"
                                      Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                                      BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                                      BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                                      ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"
                                      Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                                      ContentTransitions="{TemplateBinding ContentTransitions}"
                                      HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                                      Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                                      VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}">
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <PointerUpThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" />
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Pressed"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter"
                                                                       Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" 
                                                                    Value="{StaticResource IconHoverColor}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter"
                                                               Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                            Value="{StaticResource IconHoverTextColor}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <PointerUpThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" />
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter"
                                                                       Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                                    Value="{StaticResource SignInDisableStateColor}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="FocusStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Focused">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" 
                                                                       Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" 
                                                                    Value="{StaticResource IconHoverColor}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="PointerFocused">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" 
                                                                       Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" 
                                                                    Value="{StaticResource IconHoverColor}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Unfocused" />
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    </ContentPresenter>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Answer (score 1):

> After click I want the color to remain applied until another button is clicked, then the text in the new button clicked will change color and the previous button clicked will go back to the default color.

The focus state of the button works when the focus state is triggered from keyboard input. You could set the button's focus state in the code-behind to check if the VisualState works.

Like this:

```
MyButton.Focus(FocusState.Keyboard);
```

So want you need to do is put this line of code in the click event of the button.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have tried this solution but again the focus is getting removed whenever control is getting shifted from it.

Comment: No, it didn't solve my issue. Focused VisualState is working fine but it's not appropriate for my issue. Focus is getting remove whenever I move cursor.

Comment: @Laxmi It looks like you want to make the button change style after it is pressed and keep it until the next button is clicked, right? If it is, then changing the state is not the correct way to do it. You need to directly change the button's style like background and manage it in the code behind.

Comment: How can we achieve the same in a listview binded with two textblock of the different foreground colors and then change foreground color on point hover?